# I wonder how can I connect tomcat to oracle jdbc pool

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, jdbc

Is my code right?
in context.xml I add like this. Maybe something wrong with driveClassName or url?

```
<Resource  name="jdbcoracle"   auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
 factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
maxActive="20"
maxIdle="1"
maxWait="100"
username="test"
password="test"
driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:8080/orcl"/>
```

in web.xml in both tomcat and project add like this

```
<resource-ref> 
<description>oracle Connection</description> 
<res-ref-name>jdbc/oracle</res-ref-name> 
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type> 
<res-auth>Container</res-auth> 
</resource-ref>
```

but still appears to be

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.naming.NamingException: Could not load resource factory class [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory]
```

So what should I do? BTW I change my tomcat port number to 8081 because 8080 didn't work.

Comment: why is there a hash in your <res-ref-name>

Comment: Which version of Tomcat is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the reference](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#Oracle_8i,_9i_&_10g) this looks good with one exception (if you just copied/pasted your declarations):

In your `<Resource>` declaration you have `name="jdbcoracle"` while in your `<resource-ref>` you use `jdbc/oracle` - note the slash.

I'm only seeing this 8 hours after my initial answer: You're declaring the database URL to point to port 8080 - this is typically an administrative interface (and the reason why tomcat can't run on this port) while Oracle's DB port used to be 1521 (unless you changed it).

In addition, check your classpath as Jens suggests in his answer.

Comment: Now rather than just copy others' code I have known the meaning of every row of xml code and manage to connect!

Answer (score 0):

You miss the `tomcat-dbcp.jar` in your classpath. Download and add it to the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the White paper.  Universal Connection Pool (UCP) with Tomcat here. 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/planned-unplanned-rlb-ucp-tomcat-2265175.pdf